# Why did 'apt-get install ffmpeg' fail?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I don't understand how or why apt-get install failed. It mentions ssmtp which is simple smtp which I use to send mail from my server to my Google apps account. I don't understand what is wrong or how to fix it.

I am using debian squeeze.

```
# apt-get install ffmpeg
...
Setting up libswscale0 (4:0.5.2-6) ...
Setting up ffmpeg (4:0.5.2-6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ssmtp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

# sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo: unable to resolve host debian
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ffmpeg is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up ssmtp (2.64-4) ...
hostname: Name or service not known
dpkg: error processing ssmtp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 ssmtp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you set your system's host name to "debian" when setting it up. The installer should have added an entry for that to `/etc/hosts`, but it seems to not be there any longer.

Add an entry like this, if you don't see a line with "debian" on it already:

```
127.0.0.1    debian
```

You'll have to start your text editor with `sudo` to be allowed to save the changes.

Comment: wow, right on. I had no idea ffmpeg used email at all, before today (edit, i'll accept in 2 min when it allows me)

Answer (score 1):

The failure is unrelated to `ffmpeg`, it's due to `ssmtp`. When you ran `apt-get install ffmpeg`, you already had the `ssmtp` package in an unpacked, but not fully-installed state, which in Debian terminology is called “installed but not configured”. That [configuration stage](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html#s-configdetails) mainly runs the package's `postinst` script, which typically registers the package's components with the appropriate service (shared libraries, menu entries, etc.). When `apt-get install` has finished installing (i.e. unpacking) the packages named on the command line and their dependencies, it “configures” every package (the underlying dpkg command is `dpkg --configure --pending`).

[Warren Young has already explained why `ssmtp` couldn't be configured.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7736/why-did-apt-get-install-ffmpeg-fail/7737#7737)